# Find all differentiable functions $f:[0;2] \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $\int_{0}^{2}xf(x)dx=f(0)+f(2)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, contest-math

Find all differentiable functions $f:[0;2] \to \Bbb{R}$, with $f'$ continuous, such that the function $e^{-x}f(x)$ is decreasing on $[0;1]$ and increasing on $[1;2]$, and                    $\int_{0}^{2}xf(x)dx=f(0)+f(2)$.

I'm stuck with this problem. Taking $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$, we have $g'(x)=e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))$, so $f'(x)\le f(x)$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $f'(x)\ge f(x)$ for $x\in [1;2]$.

Comment: What makes you think that $f$ is positive on $[0,1]$?

Comment: My mistake. I thought it had something to do with attaining a minimum point,where the derivative changes its sign, but it can also be monotonic

Comment: Anyway the condition of decreasing in $[0,1]$ and increasing in $[1,2]$ makes $(e^{-x}f(x))'(1)=0$ what means $f'(1)=f(1)$.

Comment: I don't know it this can help but $\displaystyle \int_0^2 f'(t)\left( 1-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)  dt =0$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $g(t)=\exp(-t)f(t)$. We have: $\displaystyle\int_0^1 tf(t)dt=\int_0^1 t\exp(t) g(t)dt$ and integrating by parts:

$$\int_0^1 tf(t)dt=\big [(t-1)\exp(t)g(t)\big ]_0^1 -\int_0^1 (t-1) \exp(t)g^{\prime}(t) dt=f(0)-\int_0^1 (t-1) \exp(t)g^{\prime}(t) dt$$

In the same manner:

$$\int_1^2 tf(t)dt=\big [(t-1)\exp(t)g(t)\big ]_1^2 -\int_1^2 (t-1) \exp(t)g^{\prime}(t) dt=f(2)-\int_1^2 (t-1) \exp(t)g^{\prime}(t) dt$$

So we have:

$$f(0)+f(2)=f(0)-\int_0^1 (t-1) \exp(t)g^{\prime}(t) dt+f(2)-\int_1^2 (t-1) \exp(t)g^{\prime}(t) dt$$
and hence

$$-\int_0^1 (t-1) \exp(t)g^{\prime}(t) dt-\int_1^2 (t-1) \exp(t)g^{\prime}(t) dt=0$$

But the two terms are negative, hence we have:

$$\int_0^1 (t-1) \exp(t)g^{\prime}(t) dt=\int_1^2 (t-1) \exp(t)g^{\prime}(t) dt=0$$

Now $g^{\prime}$ has a constant sign on $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$, so one get $g^{\prime}=0$, and $f$ is necessarily $c\exp(t)$ for a constant $c$. One verify that these functions are solutions.

Comment: nice answer +1!

Comment: @Kelenner "But the two terms are negative" why?

Comment: Cool solution, but instead of $exp(t)g'(t)$ you can just write $f'(x)-f(x)$.

Comment: @rlartiga For the first, you have $g^{\prime}\leq 0$ (on $[0,1]$), $t-1\leq 0$, and so the function under the integral sign is $\geq 0$. With the minus sign, the first term is hence $\leq 0$. Same thing for the second.

Comment: @Kelenner thanks!